# How to close 'react-burger-menu' by clicking outside menu and menu item

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hamburger-menu, react-functional-component

What is the most efficient way to close menu on click in React functional component?
I'm trying to get `<Menu />` close on clicking either `<Link />`or outside menu. Currently it stays open when I navigate to other component.

I use: https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu

**MobileMenu.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { elastic as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu';
import './MobileMenu.scss';

const MobileMenu = () => {
    
const [menuOpenState, setMenuOpenState] = useState(false)

const MyContext = React.createContext();

// const showSettings = event =>{
//     event.preventDefault();
// }
  return (
    <div className="mobileMenu" id="outer-container"> 
        <Menu right pageWrapId={ "page-wrap" } outerContainerId={ "outer-container"} isOpen={ false }>
            <main id="page-wrap">
                <MyContext.Provider value={{
                    isMenuOpen: menuOpenState,
                    toggleMenu: () => setMenuOpenState(!menuOpenState),
                    stateChangeHandler: (newState) => setMenuOpenState(newState.isOpen)
                }}>
                </MyContext.Provider>
                <Link id="home "to={'/'} className="menu-item">home</Link>
                <Link id="projects" to={'/projects'} className="menu-item">projects</Link>
                <Link id="experiment" to={'/experiment'} className="menu-item">experiment</Link>
                {/* <a onClick={ showSettings } className="menu-item--small" href="/">Settings</a> */}
            </main>
        </Menu>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MobileMenu
```

Comment: Do not know about efficiency, but this hook can do the trick  https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/

Comment: Go with the implementation @DavidGaloyan shared. That is how it would be implemented in a component, and wrapping it all in a reusable hook is nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is add a `div` element with absolute value and stretch the entire screen display on let's say `z-index: 100;` and your menu on `z-index: 101;` and open the element only with the menu and set the `onClick={() =>setMenuOpenState(false)}` this way it's a little more efficient